# VS2010 and VS2012 “Script Documents” section never appears, and I can't debug JavaScript

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

Tools:

Windows 7,
Visual Studio 2010 and 2012,
IE 9,
ASP.NET 4.0,
MVC4

Until a couple of days ago I had been able to debug by using the Script Documents section in the Solution Explorer. Now, the Scripts Documents section does not appear when Start Debugging (F5).

**I do have IE set as the default browser.**

**Using "debugger;" has no effect.**

**Configuration is set to "Active (Debug)."**

**Silverlight debugging is off.**

**I have 'repaired' the Visual Studio 2010 inatallation.**

I have no idea how to correct this frustrating situation. What have I done to displease the VS gods?

Thanks for any advice!

Arnold

Comment: is silverlight debugging being turned on?

Comment: Hi naveen. Silverlight debugging is off. I saw that suggestion in another post but forgot to list it here. Thanks.

Comment: @naveen. I've just put VS 2010 in Maintenance Mode - trying to "repair" the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might be facing the same issue I think I have it figured out. I have spent days and nights tearing my hair out on this, along with my usual duties. It's unfortunate that I couldn't get "real" work done because I was chasing tool strangeness.

I had the following line in_Layout.cshtml:

[image]

**When I removed that line, Script Documents reappeared.**

I'm going to mark this as 'resolved,' however, if anyone else can proffer a reason for the behavior of the software, I would like to understand.

Thanks,

Arnold

Comment: if anyone else cant see the image (due to firewall/internet rules), its  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />                     http://forums.asp.net/t/1848424.aspx?VS2010+and+VS2012+Script+Documents+section+never+appears+I+can+t+debug+Javascript+

Answer (score 7):

This fixed worked for me to get the Script Documents node back:

1. In the Website Project within the Solution Explorer, right-click any 'ol .aspx page and click "Browse With..."
2. Select another browser (Chrome, Firefox) and click "Set As Default" and close the window
3. Launch your website through the debugger. When it's finished, stop the debugger.
4. Repeat steps 1 and 2, but select Internet Explorer in Step 2 as "Set As Default"
5. Repeat step 3 and it should work. This will get your javascript debugging back.

Answer (score 2):

I originally got into the same situation when I down-graded from ie10 to ie9 to match the user community here.

Removing the meta tag made no difference for me.  No surprise there.

Thanks to User1503081's suggestion, I finally resolved it by doing a Repair install of VS2012 Update 3 in my case.  Would have given props to User1503081 directly but my "Reputation Points" don't add up. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I attempted the above answers (at least those which were relevant), but found the solution in re-running the VS2012 update 2.